# PHP / MySQL - Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have the following code, it worked fine on XAMPP Server. Now i copied the PHP-Code and the MySQL-Database to a new Server with manually installed Apache, PHP and MySQL.

I get the following error:

> Warning: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php:87
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php(87):
>   mysqli_stmt->execute()
>
> #1 [internal function]:
>   session->read('3r7jkgjk93pu9fc...')
>
> #2 C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php(43):
>   session_regenerate_id(true)
>
> #3 C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php(19):
>   session->start_session('_sichereSitzung...', false)
>
> #4 C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.php(16):
>   session->__construct()
>
> #5 C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\index.php(21):
>   require_once('C:\intranet\apa...')
>
> #6 {main} thrown in
>   C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php on line 87
>   Catchable fatal error: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create
>   session ID: user (path: ) in
>   C:\intranet\apache24\htdocs\content\php\session.class.php

on line 43r code here

This is my Code:

```
class session {

    function __construct() {
        // set custom session functions
        session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'open'), array($this, 'close'), array($this, 'read'), array($this, 'write'), array($this, 'destroy'), array($this, 'gc'));

       // this line prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handler
       register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

       // start the session
       $this->start_session('_sichereSitzung-A3i6Zz', FALSE);
    }

    function start_session($session_name, $secure) {
        // make sure the session cookie is not accessible via javascript
        $httponly = true;

        // get session cookie parameters 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 

        // set the parameters
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

        // prevent javascript from getting session id
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        // change the session name 
        session_name($session_name);

        // now we can start the session
        session_start();

        // this line regenerates the session and delete the old one
        // it also generates a new encryption key in the database
        session_regenerate_id(true); 
    }

    function open() {
        // configuration file
        require_once('config.php');     

        // the sql data
        require_once(PHP_PATH . 'sqluserdata.php');

        //open mysqli-connection
        $mysqli = new mysqli(SESS_HOST, SESS_USER, SESS_PW, SESS_DB, SESS_PORT);

        //bind the mysqli-connection to variable
        $this->db = $mysqli;

        return true;
    }

    function close() {
        // close mysqli-connection
        $this->db->close();

        return true;
    }

    function read($id) {
        $min=1;
        $max=200;
        $rand = mt_rand($min,$max);

        // only run garbage collection random on page load
        if ($rand == 1) {
            // garbage collection
            $this->gc(259200);
        }

        // if statement doesnt exists create statement
        if (!isset($this->read_stmt)) {
            $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM session WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }

        // bind session parameter, run statement, bind result to variable
        $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->read_stmt->execute();
        $this->read_stmt->store_result();
        $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
        $this->read_stmt->fetch();

        return $data;
    }

    function write($id, $data) {
        // bind time to variable
        $time = time();

        // if statement doesnt exists, prepare statement
        if(!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
            $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO session (id, access, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        }

        // bind variables, execute statement
        $this->w_stmt->bind_param('sis', $id, $time, $data);
        $this->w_stmt->execute();

        return true;
    }

    function destroy($id) {
        // if statement doesnt exists, prepare statement
        if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
            $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE id = ?");
        }

        // bind parameters, execute statement
        $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->delete_stmt->execute();

        return true;
    }

    function gc($max) {
        // if statement doesnt exists, prepare statement
        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {
            $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM session WHERE access < ?");
        }

        // calculate time to delete
        $old = time() - $max;

        // bind parameters, execute query
        $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
        $this->gc_stmt->execute();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Anyone know this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with your PHP code - it's an error that MySQL sends.

Basically, the [MySQL server has crashed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html):

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
>   that the server timed out and closed the connection. In this case, you
>   normally get one of the following error codes (which one you get is
>   operating system-dependent).

Check out the possible problems in the page I've linked to. The common problems are:

- you're doing a very complex query that the server cannot handle;
- you have misconfigured your MySQL server.

Does the error happen all the time when you run the queries? Or is it some specific query what it crashes on? You should check that first.